# Migration from Jboss 4.0.3SP1 to 4.0.4GA. Could not inherit from final class. Deployment failed:

Tags: jsf, jboss, war, jboss-4.0.x

I am trying to migrate from my .war application from JBoss 4.0.3 SP1 to 4.0.4 GA. I am not able to deploy the .war files here in JBoss 4.0.4  getting some `VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class` which I don't get it when I deploy in my previous version JBoss. FYI, my application uses  JSF for UI. Is there some library changes that does not work  for the JSF in this 4.0.4 GA version  or can someone tell me why  my .war  files are not getting deployed?

```
15:44:52,636 ERROR [MainDeployer] Could not create deployment: file:/C:/jboss-4.0.4.GA/server/default/deploy/bland.war/    
java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247
```

Comment: usually it is a classpath problem, probably you have 2 version of the same library

Comment: Hey, i fixed this issue by replcaing the ..default\deploy\jbossw.sar file of Jboss 4.0.4 by ..default\deploy\jbossws14.sar from previous version  Jboss 4.0.3SP. Since i am still using this previous folder that contains older jar files but keeping all the core lib from new Jboss, I am still pretty much not sure that it might give me a good performance. But I can see my application working till now.
thanks